# Jsoup removes multiple whitespace in string

Tags: java, jsoup, xss

I am trying to use jsoup.clean with

```
    Whitelist.relaxed().preserveRelativeLinks(true);
    Jsoup.clean(html, wl);
```

My html is a string `message = "This is a simple string messages with  double  spaces"`

There are double spaces in the string. But when I do `.clean()`, it trims the spaces. I want to preserve these spaces. How do I do it? Event `.basic()` and `.simpleText()` does not work.

Comment: Do you want to keep a maximum of a single space?

Comment: @RahalKanishka i want to keep the string as it is..if it has double/single/tab spaces, it should be as it is

Comment: can you elaborate what you actually want to do with this example String

Comment: @RahalKanishka this is the query parameter in the url. So to avoid XSS i am using jsoup as the user can add script in this. Now when i have a normal string and if there are 2 spaces between the "with  double" if you see that gets trimmed. I want to avoid that.

Comment: JSoup is only for processing HTML input. For other input, you prevent XSS by encoding the output. See rules #0 and #1 at: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 4):

[There is an overload](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#clean(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.jsoup.safety.Safelist,org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings)) for `clean` that takes in a `Document.outputSettings` object:

```
public static String clean​(String bodyHtml, String baseUri, Safelist safelist, Document.OutputSettings outputSettings)
```

[Using that, you can set](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html#prettyPrint()) `prettyPrint` to false:

> public boolean prettyPrint()

> Get if pretty printing is enabled. Default is true. If disabled, the HTML output methods will not re-format the output, and the output will generally look like the input.

So you end up with something like this:

```
Whitelist.relaxed().preserveRelativeLinks(true);
Jsoup.clean(html, "", wl, new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
```

That should get you what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I already got this working with pretty false. Forgot to update it here.

Comment: I don't suppose you could mark this as the answer then @Swaprks?